# Minimization of $\|x\|_1$ subject to $\|Ax - y\| \leq \eta$ has an $m$-sparse solution when minimizer $x^*$ is unique

Tags: optimization, convex-optimization, signal-processing, sparsity

Given matrix $A \in \mathbb{R}^{m \times n}$, vector $y \in \mathbb{R}^m$, and scalar $ \eta \geq 0$,

$$\begin{array}{ll} \underset{x \in \mathbb{R}^n}{\text{minimize}} & \|x\|_1\\ \text{subject to} & \|Ax - y\| \leq \eta\end{array}$$

It should be assumed here that the norm in the constraint is any proper norm in $\mathbb{R}^m$. Let $x^*$ denote the unique minimizer. I want to show that $x^*$ is $m$-sparse, that is

$$|\text{supp}(x^*)| \leq m$$

My understanding is that the proof given for Theorem 3.1 in Simon Foucart & Holger Rauhut's [A Mathematical Introduction to Compressive Sensing](https://doi.org/10.1007/978-0-8176-4948-7) [[PDF](https://www2.karlin.mff.cuni.cz/%7Evybiral/Sem-2017/Rauhut.pdf) – 6.6 MB] should work. It is a proof of this fact for basis pursuit, i.e., $Ax=y$ instead of $\|Ax - y\| \leq \eta$.

My questions are:

1. Does the proof which I linked above indeed cover this case as well?
2. Are there any other interesting proofs of this fact which use convex optimization or more general results from optimization?

Comment: any norm on $R^m$

Comment: Is it ethical to link to the PDF? Why not just print-screen the proof and post it here?

Comment: The edits look good. I wasn't sure what the community rules are regarding placing an image of a textbook proof in a question. Is it better to use a print-screen or write out in mathjax?

Comment: Print-screen should be fine provided you cite its origin. MathJax is even better than print-screen because it is text and can be found by search engines. However, it is more time-consuming.